# The rigidity of $2$-dim sphere with constant sectional curvature in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n> 3$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, rigidity

If there is a smooth isometric embedding $f: (S^2, g)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, where $(S^2, g)$ is a sphere with Riemannian metric such that the corresponding sectional curvature is equal to $1$, and $n\geq 4$. Is  Is $f(S^2)$ always $\mathbb{S}^2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ modulo an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: If you mean $\mathbb{R}^3\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ as a vector subspace, then the answer is no. There are many isometric embeddings of $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^4$ that is not extrinsically flat (just roll it up like a [fruit roll up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_Roll-Ups)).

Comment: @WillieWong, my question should be claified as the follows: Is $(^2)$ always $\mathbb{S}^2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ modulo an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Since R^1 smoothly embeds isometrically in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of R^2, R^3 does the same in R^6. So if we first place S^2 in R^3 as the usual unit sphere, and then embed R^3 in an arbitrarily small neighborhood of R^6, this provides a counterexample to your question.

Comment: (Although you don't state explicitly what you mean by "S^2 ⊆ R^n".)

Comment: @WillieWong’s counterexample is still one for your new version of the question.

Comment: The question refers to rigidity, i.e. does the group of isometries of $\mathbb R^n$ act transitively on the isometric embeddings of $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^n$.  As mentioned, the answer is generally no.

Comment: I guess "isometric embedding" is to be interpreted in the Riemannian sense, i.e., infinitesimally isometric, and not in the stronger metric sense (distance-preserving). [The standard embedding in $\mathbf{R}^3$ is not distance-preserving!]